# How I can get the distance in a glm perspective projection that will represent 1 pixel in my screen?

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, glm-math

I have the following glm perspective projection

```
world.cameraProjection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), app.aspectRatio, 0.0f, 100.0f);
world.cameraProjection = glm::scale(world.cameraProjection, world.scale);
world.cameraView = glm::translate(world.cameraProjection, world.camera);
```

And I will like to guess the value I will have to use to draw a line that has pixel perfect width.

I know the width of my screen, and I'm trying now to translate the percentage of the viewport that represents 1 pixel into a distance for the glm cameraView. So even if the zoom changes the line I'm drawing will appear always the same size in the screen.

Is there a function in glm to do this?

Comment: For 2D graphics consider using orthographic projection

Comment: so in this case I need perspective because I need a zoom, but I want to draw a pixel perfect grid and I need this

Comment: You can zoom in orthographic projection too.

Comment: but you can't rotate

Comment: @ellipticaldoor Of course you can rotate. You can do all the transformations that you can do in perspective projection. The type of projection does not limit the transformations. Why do you think so?

Answer (score 3):

When using [Perspective projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Perspective_projection), the x- and y-distance that represents one pixel depends on the depth (z-distance).

[image]

A projected size in normalized device space can be transformed to a size in view space with:

```cpp
aspect = width / height
tanFov = tan(fov_y / 2.0) * 2.0;

dist_x = ndc_dist_x * z_eye * tanFov * aspect;
dist_y = ndc_dist_y * z_eye * tanFov;
```

What you want is that:

```
height * (ndc_dist_y + 1) / 2 == 1
```

So if you know the z-distance of an object, the formula is:

```cpp
dist = z_eye * (2.0 / height - 1.0) * tan(fov_y / 2.0) * 2.0
```

where `fov_y` is the field of view in radiant, `height` is the height of the field of view in pixels, and `z_eye` is the absolute distance from the object to the camera.

---

Consider using parallel projection ([Orthographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection)), where the size of the projection does not depend on the distance from the camera.

Comment: I'm having trouble with this formula. If `dist` is supposed to be the height of 1 pixel, why would a positive `z_eye` and a `height` of ie. `720` produce a negative value?

Comment: @iLoch I have no idea what you're taking about. Anyway, the view space z-axis points out of the view. View space is a right haded system, x points right and y points up

Comment: Sure alright. What coordinate space is `z_eye` supposed to be in?

Comment: @iLoch `eye` == view space